# How to write a batch file to set svn:ignore for a particular directory in every branch of a directory tree?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, svnignore

To explain with an example, the structure of my project is `RootDirectory`, there are inside it 3 branch directories DirA, DirB and DirC.

Let's say the target folder is `bin` folder. `bin` is present directly in `dirC`, under 1 level in dirB( DirB->Dir BA-> bin) and under two levels in DirA (DirA->DirAA->DirAAA->bin).

Now I have to run a batch script in root directory that should transverse the entire tree, search for bin folders and put svn ignore only on bin folders.

With my current program, I can transverse, but the loop is running for the subfolders of `bin` also. Thus am unable to stop at `bin`, go into that and implement `svn:ignore`.

The requirement in gist:

1. Outer loop to transverse the entire tree
2. Inner loop to stop at bin, cd to bin, implement `svn ignore`, break.
3. Outer loop continues to next instance of `bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recursively call a batch file to achieve this.

An example batch file called `recursive.bat` could look like this (note: this is just to get you started, you might have to do extra things to deal with file names and directories with spaces in them and possibly other anomalies...):

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL

IF "%1"=="" (
  SET BATDIR=%~dp0
) ELSE (
  SET BATDIR=%1
)

ECHO Currently in %CD%

REM Trick to get current directory name (not path)
FOR %%* IN (.) DO (
  IF %%~n*==bin (
    REM Currently inside a directory called bin
    ECHO Setting SVN prop for %CD% and exiting recursion...
    REM Insert your SVN ignore command here
    GOTO :EOF
  )
)

REM Loop over all subdirectories in this directory 
FOR /D %%D IN ("*") DO (
  ECHO Recursing into subdir "%%D"
  PUSHD "%%D"
  CALL "%BATDIR%\recursive.bat"
  POPD
)
```

Invoke it as `recursive.bat` (no parameters). The current directory trick is copied from [Get current folder name by a DOS command?](https://superuser.com/q/160702/165694)

By the way, if you happen to use TortoiseSVN then you can instruct it via configuration settings to always ignore `bin` directories.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot . However can you please explain more on the svn configuration settings. I don't have a bin folder or even some directories on the svn main structure. In future they will be added and there will be a need to commit. At that time, no bin folder should be allowed to commit, if it is inside a particular root directory. Hence the need to run a batch file in that directory. Please let me know if there is some other simpler way.

Comment: Do you use TortoiseSVN?